# How to keep a dot drawn on canvas at a fixed point on screen, even when the canvas is pinch zoomed? - Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas

I have a background image as a drawable in my custom view. This drawable may be pinch zoomed or moved.

Currently I need a green dot that is drawn on the image to be stationary relative to the screen. That is, it should be always at the same position with the pin as shown below. (Of course, the pin is simply an ImageView and does NOT move at all!)

[image]

I **have successfully made it** stationary relative to the screen, **when** the map behind is **moved** as follows in my custom view, MapView:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: { // triggered as long as finger movers
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                // update the starting point if the 'Start' button is not yet pressed
                // to ensure the screen center (i.e. the pin) is always the starting point
                if (!isStarted) {
                    Constant.setInitialX(Constant.INITIAL_X - dx);
                    Constant.setInitialY(Constant.INITIAL_Y - dy);
                    if ((historyXSeries.size() > 0) && (historyYSeries.size() > 0)) {
                        // new initial starting point
                        historyXSeries.set(0, Constant.INITIAL_X);
                        historyYSeries.set(0, Constant.INITIAL_Y);
                    }
                }

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }
```

By doing that above, my green dot stays there, when the background image is moved.

**But I have problems in trying to make it stay there, when the background image is zoomed.**

**Essentially, I don't really understand how `canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor)` works, and therefore I cannot move the green dot accordingly like what I have done in the simple moving case.**

I think something should be added in the scale listener handler below, could anybody help me fill that part?

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f)); // 1 ~ 10

            // HOW TO MOVE THE GREEN DOT HERE??

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
```

Or please at least explain how `canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor)` works, and how may I move the green dot accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the canvas is thought to scale everything according to the scale factor, so while going against the zoom is possible, it is probably not the best approach.  However, if this is what you're looking for, I will help you as best as I can.

I am assuming the following:

- Scale factor is relative to the current zoom (old zoom is always scale factor 1).  If this is not the case, then you should observe the zoom values after scaling roughly 200% two times and seeing if the resulting scale factor is 4 or 3 (exponential or linear).  You can achieve the results below by normalizing the scale factor to 2 for a zoom factor of 200%, for example.  You'll have to remember the old scale factor in order to do so.
- No rotation is performed

If this is the case then following can be said for a marker with respect to the zoom center.

For every horizonal pixel *x* away from the zoom center after zoom, its original position could be calculated to be:  `zoom_center_x + *x* / scale_factor` (or alternatively `zoom_center_x + (marker_x - zoom_center_x) / scale_factor)`.  In other words, if zoom center is `(50, 0)` and the marker is `(100, 0)` with a scale factor of 2, then the x position of the marker prior to the zoom was `50 + (100 - 50) / 2 or 75.`  Obviously, if the marker is in the same position of the zoom center, then the x position will be the same as the zoom center.  Similarly, if the scale is 1, then the x position for the marker will be the same as it is now.

The same can be applied to the y axis.

While I can't know exactly how to set the position of your marker, I would expect the code to look something like:

```
Point zoomCenter = detector.getZoomCenter();
// Set marker variable here
marker.setX(Math.round(zoomCenter.getX() + ((double)(marker.getX() - zoomCenter.getX())) / mScaleFactor));
marker.setY(Math.round(zoomCenter.getY() + ((double)(marker.getY() - zoomCenter.getY())) / mScaleFactor));
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I jsut find out that the zoom is always relative to the ORIGINAL size. e.g., 2x on the original, and then another 2x on the previous. This will lead the mScaleFactor to be 4x.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng, well that complicates it a bit.  Save the last zoom, and try performing new_zoom/old_zoom in order to achieve the relative zoom factor.  In this way 2 is twice as zoomed as 1, and 4 is twice as zoomed as 2, etc.